# Add margin to a specific section top and bottom using twitter bootstrap class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I add margin to a specific section top and bottom using twitter bootstrap class? I can do this using my custom css like `.my_section{margin:100px 0}` but I want to do it by bootstrap class (if any).

Comment: You need to add custom class.

Comment: Thanks Mr monoj Kumar. I can do this by custom class . but I am looking for bootstrap typography.

Comment: I believe that there isn't such a function within Bootstrap, you will have to use a custom class for it. The closest Bootstrap has is `.jumbotron` class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bad idea to add your own class in order to apply the styling.

Firstly, it means that you're less like to accidentally apply the style override to another element on the page (or, more likely, someone who comes along later and adds another element with the same Bootstrap class).

Also you can use your class name to semantically describe the override:

```
<button class="spaced-button btn btn-primary"> ...

.spaced-button {
  margin:10px 0;
}
```